# How to create multiple directories use Bash

Tags: linux, bash

I want to create ten folders named `foo1java`, `foo2c`, `foo3python`, etc.

I tried this but it creates too many directories:

```
mkdir foo{1..3}{java,c,python}

foo1c/     foo1python/  foo2java/    foo3c/     foo3python/
foo1java/  foo2c/       foo2python/  foo3java/
```

I just want map the numbers to the languages: `1` to `java`, `2` to `c`, `3` to `python`, etc.

How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
i=1; for j in java c python; do mkdir foo${i}${j}; i=$((i+1)); done
```

gives directories

```
foo1java
foo2c
foo3python
```

To add more languages, just keep filling the word list after `python` with space-separated entities. The integer counter will keep up.

---

*Addition:* "Bashier" (but not better, so I would prefer the above solution, since it is more portable (even though it probably doesn't matter in this case)):

```
list=(java c python); i=1; while [ $i -lt ${#list} ]; do mkdir foo${i}${list[i-1]}; let i++; done
```

Just fill the array `list` with more entries as before.

Comment: I hope to see short command line to solve this problem, if there is no any better answers, I would mark this answer. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

It's a static mapping, so factor it out.

```
mkdir foo{1java,2c,3python}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another possible way (bash)

```
  arr=(java c python); for((i = 1; i <= ${#arr[@]}; i++)); do mkdir foo${i}${arr[i-1]} ; done
```

Answer (score 0):

No looping...

```
paste <( printf '%s\n' foo{1..3} ) \
      <( printf '%s\n' java c python ) |tr -d '\t' | xargs mkdir -p
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you:

```
parallel --xapply mkdir foo{1}{2} ::: {1..3} ::: {java,c,python}
```